# Decide the limit of the sequence $\{n^3/2^n\}_{n=0}^\infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Decide the limit of the sequence $\{n^3/2^n\}_{n=0}^\infty$

I've verified that the sequence is indeed monotonic decreasing for $n \ge 11$ using induction. Also, the sequence is bounded. This implies the sequence is convergent, and I know the limit is $0$.

However for $|n^3/2^n - 0| \le \epsilon$ where $\epsilon > 0$, I find it extremely difficult to decide the value of $N\in \mathbb N$. I get the inequality $3 \cdot \ln(n) - \ln(\epsilon)\over \ln(2) $ $\le n$. But I need an explicit value of $N$ and not some value depending on $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using series: apply the root test to the positive series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^3}{2^n}\;:\;\;\sqrt[n]{\frac{n^3}{2^n}}=\frac{\sqrt[n]{n^3}}2\xrightarrow [n\to\infty]{}\frac12<1$$

So the series converges and thus the sequence converges to zero.

**Added on request:** Try to prove with induction that

$$\frac{n^3}{2^n}<\frac1n\;,\;\;\text{say for}\;\;n\ge 16\ldots$$

and then the squeeze theorem.

Or using $\;\epsilon >0\;$:

$$\frac{n^3}{2^n}<\epsilon\iff 2^n\epsilon>n^3\ge 64\implies n>\frac{\log {\frac{64}\epsilon}}2\;,\;\;\;n\ge 4$$

Comment: Thanks, DonAntonio. Your answer is correct. However in the textbook I'm reading this exercise is given before the chapter on series, so it should be do able using just the theory of sequences.

Comment: But you tagged your question as "sequences-and-series", @NicolasLykkeIversen ...

Comment: It is because there is no topic called 'sequences'

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks.

Comment: But do you know how to proof the limit of a sequence in case you know there exists a limit ? There must be many situations like this where you cannot isolate $n$ in the inequality ?

Comment: Well, you can try some induction + the squeeze theorem. I added some hints on this, @NicolasLykkeIversen .

Comment: Thanks DonAntonio, I will try out your hints.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again DonAntonio, but $n > log(64 / epsilon) /2, n \ge 4$ only gives a bound for $n$ satisfying $2^n\epsilon > 64$ ? How do I know this $n$ will satisfy $2^n\epsilon > n^3$ ?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Exponential function goes faster than polynomial

For all real constants $a$ and $b$ such that $a > 1$,

> $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n^b}{a^n} = 0$$

Comment: I'm familiar with $O$-notation. But is this rigorous enough ?